# WPF ClickOnce : How are Digest values calculated

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I'm trying to understand how *DigestValues* are calculated in ClickOnce Application Manifest. 
Here's the scenario: There're 3 projects :

- `App`
- `Lib A`
- `Lib B`

Their dependency is as follows:
`App --(depends on) --> Lib A --(depends on) --> Lib B`

Now if i make a change only in `Lib B` it causes the Digest Values of `App` & `Lib A` to change. This means that all 3 files has to downloaded during an update where-as the change is only in `Lib B` .

I'm thinking that only the DigestValue of `Lib B` should change. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an issue with visual studio. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404267.aspx

Specifically:

> If you use Visual Studio to compile your application, it will generate
>   new hash signatures for all files whenever you rebuild the entire
>   project. In this case, all assemblies will be downloaded to the
>   client, although only a few assemblies may have changed.

So I would make sure you're not rebuilding assemblies in visual studio if they're not really changing, and that should keep the digest values the same.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked. The assemblies are never recompiled.